# Java Scanner is appearing before print()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.out

I am trying to print a string before asking for the input while using `Scanner`, but it keeps making the input appear before the string. I can't find any reason why it's doing this. I have attached the full code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        long number = scanner.nextLong();
        
        if (number % 5 ==0) {
            System.out.print("Fizz");
        }
        else if (number % 3 ==0) {
            System.out.println("Buzz");
        }
        else if ((number % 5 ==0) && (number % 3 ==0)) {
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(number + " Is neither Fizzable or Buzzable");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "it keeps making the input appear before the string" What do you mean?

Comment: And FYI, your program won't work as expected. Try 15, it will only print "Fizz".

Comment: I see "Number:" before it asks me for the input when I run it. There are errors in your logic though (you need to check for the combined case (3 and 5) before the individual cases.

Comment: "
        else if ((number % 5 ==0) && (number % 3 ==0)) {
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
        }
" this is unreachable as currently written

Comment: Ah yeah, it was in the wrong order.

I mean, when it prints to the terminal it will ask me to input the number then will print `Number: Fizz` rather than printing `Number: ` then asking for the input and then printing `Fizz`

Comment: Your code works fine in my IDE, must be something strange with your Netbeans.

Comment: Yeah thought so, might just switch IDE

Comment: I use Netbeans and it works fine by me. I suggest cleaning up the project an rebuild. Maybe that'll help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.out.print` may not flush to the screen immediately, but you could flush it explicitly:

```
System.out.print("Number: ");
System.out.flush(); // here!
long number = scanner.nextLong();
```

Comment: That still didn't work, I'm using Netbeans and not sure if it's a problem on their end or not

Comment: Might be an issue with the NetBeans console, might not.  Either way, IMHO,, best thing to do is use `println` for the prompt and just move on.  Now, if `println` doesn't solve it, _then_ I'd say we've got a proper mystery on our hands....(;->)

Comment: Aha! Yeah probably just going to switch IDE